# How to remove empty Bs from PostgreSQL query only if other Bs have a value (for each A)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I have a table with scientific and common (vernacular) names for plants.

```
               gensp       vernacular
Allamanda blanchetii                 
Allamanda blanchetii  Alamanda morada
Allamanda blanchetii Purple allamanda
  Allamanda puberula                 
  Aspidosperma cuspa                 
  Aspidosperma cuspa    Guatambuzinho
```

I need this to become:

```
               gensp                        vernacular
Allamanda blanchetii Alamanda morada, Purple allamanda
  Allamanda puberula                                  
  Aspidosperma cuspa                     Guatambuzinho
```

I have tried the following SQL (on Postgres).

```
select gensp,string_agg(vernacular,', ') as vernacular from (
    select distinct gen||' '||sp as gensp,spm.vernacular from sp
    join col on idsp = sp.id
    join spm on idcol = col.id
    where fam = 'Apocynaceae' and gen||' '||sp != ''
    order by gensp,vernacular
) sub
group by gensp
```

But it returns:

```
               gensp                          vernacular
Allamanda blanchetii , Alamanda morada, Purple allamanda
  Allamanda puberula                                    
  Aspidosperma cuspa                     , Guatambuzinho
```

Notice how the empty vernacular names appear on the aggregate string. So I need to remove these lines, but only if some other line have a name (or else *Allamanda puberula* would be removed from the query).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` and `coalesce` to deal with empty or `null` `vernacular` values.

```
select sp, 
       coalesce(
         string_agg(vernacular, ', ') 
           filter (where coalesce(vernacular, '') != ''),
       '')
  from plants
 group by sp;
```

The simpler answer devised by OP, @Rodrigo:

```
select sp,
       coalesce(string_agg(nullif(vernacular,''),', '))
  from plants
  group by sp;
```

Comment: My web provider still uses PostgreSQL 9.3, where the FILTER function is not present. I'm having a hard time to translate that to CASE...THEN. Can you help, please?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out using NULLIF. Will add to the answer soon.

Comment: @Rodrigo I added an example that works without the `filter`

Comment: I added the solution I've found. It's far simpler, and to me at least it's working fine. What do you think?

Comment: One hand washes the other :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know what your query has to do with your question.  But what you are describing appears to be simple string aggregation:

```
select sp, string_agg(vernacular, ', ')
from t
group by sp;
```

Comment: Probably the OP has empty `VARCHAR`s that should be filtered out.

Comment: This creates `, Alamanda morada, Purple allamanda` where I need only `Alamanda morada, Purple allamanda`